# What conclusions can we draw from different correlations between IQ scores between subjects belonging in different groups?

Tags: correlation, variance, psychology, research-design

I was reading a presentation where research was quoted according to which children and parents who live together have IQs that are correlated with a correlation coefficient of 0.42 while children and parents who do not live together have their IQs correlated by a coefficient of 0.22 and finally subjects with no relation have IQ correlation with a correlation coefficient 0.02.

Unfortunately the presentation provided neither the source nor other information about the research design.

My question is what kind of conclusions can we draw regarding the degree that biology and environment explains variations in IQ test results and under what assumptions?

Comment: Do you have link/reference to the presentation?

Comment: No I have received in slides and it is in Greek anyway